# View dislocated after log in or cancelling firebase social login swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have developed a firebase social login but after either logging in or canceling the log window, it returns to the screen with a dislocated view. can anyone help?[image]

following is code m using for facebook

```
   @IBAction func facebookCustom(_ sender: Any) {
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
            // if user cancel the login
            if (result?.isCancelled)!{
                return
            }
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {
                self.getFBUserData()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to share your code for us to be of any help.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri exactly which code, login or moving to next view code?

Comment: The code login, moving and coming back?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri yes, functionality is working fine but this view is getting dislocated.

Comment: Show code where you create this view controller.

Comment: @inokey so I have used storyboard for this, and inside the code is login functionality, let me edit to show an example of facebook button

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of your storyboard constraints for this screen?

Comment: @inokey check the edited code

Comment: As far as I can judge from the screenshot. You need also add trailing Space to Base and top Space to Base, like you did leading and bottom.

Comment: @inokey already did that earlier but same problem

Comment: It's really hard to tell what might be the problem without seeing your layout completely. It's obvious that something is wrong with the constraints of that light blue view.

Comment: @inokey okay any idea why does this only happens after returning from login panel i.e after clicking Gmail/facebook button

Comment: It happens because of a view lifecycle, during `viewWillDissappear` and `viewWillAppear` phases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, guys, I found out what I was doing wrong, there was this line in my code which was messing up with my view and after commenting it, everything is working fine.

//view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false